# Server crashed often (Heroku environment, node.js (with express, cors) backend with MYSQL)

Tags: mysql, node.js, react-native, express, heroku

I have a mobile app that connects to a backend that I put together using node.js, the backend works great in terms of responding to the services that I have created, that bring data from the MySql database living in Heroku.

The problem is that the Heroku crash often, most of the time when I'm moving fast bewteen screens or when I do refresh to a flatlist. This is big deal issue because since i have this continuity problems I can't release my app.

I will need help of the experts here.

Today I have file for connection:

```
const mysql = require('mysql');


// BD CONNECTION USING CLEARDB

const getPool =()=>{
  return mysql.createPool({   
    host:'...',         
    user: '...',
    password: 'xxxxxx',
    database: 'hxxxxxx',
    connectionLimit:50,
    waitForConnections:true,
    reconnect:true,
    connectTimeout: 60000
   });
}
```

Example of the route for one of the services that crash the app:

```
routes.post('/getTheBestServices',(req,resp)=>{
    const zipcode = req.body.zipcode;
    const idUser = req.body.idUser;
    
    try {
        srv.retrieveBestScoredServices(idUser,zipcode,(services) =>{        
        resp.send(services);
    });
    } catch (error) {
      resp.status(500).send({"error":"Error on retrieve best scored services"});
    }
    
  });
```

Service that exist in the file ServicesDAO.js

```
const connDB = require('../db/DBConnection');

/**
 * @param {*} idUser
 * @param {*} zipcode 
 * @param {*} callback 
 */
 const retrieveBestScoredServices=(idUser,zipcode,callback)=>{

    connDB.getPool().getConnection(function(err, con){

        con.query('SELECT U.ID_USER idUserOwner'
        +'\n  WHERE S.APPROVED_STATUS=1'
        +'\n  ORDER BY S.RATING_TOTAL DESC LIMIT 20;' //I LIMITED THE QUERY
        ,[variables..], async(err, services) => {

            if (err) {
                console.log("[mysql error]",err);
            }
            else {
                //check to see if the result is empty
                if(services.length > 0){
                    con.release();
                    callback(services); 

               } 
            }          
          });    
       });
}
```

I have been working to simplify the services, I have added the line result.length > 0 to handle the response, but is still crashing.

IS NOT ALWAYS, works great if you don't stress the app, but if you ask many times the services or reload the data more than two times goes off and the entire Heroku goes down.

This is the picture of the HEROKU log:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. [Please don't post screenshots of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/354577). They can't be searched or copied, or even consumed by users of adaptive technologies like screen readers. Instead, paste the code as text directly into your question. If you select it and click the `{}` button or Ctrl+K the code block will be indented by four spaces, which will cause it to be rendered as code.

Comment: Additional DB information request FROM YOUR BACKEND MySQL, please. 
RAM size, # cores, any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server? 
Post TEXT data on justpaste.it and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
A) SELECT COUNT(*), sum(data_length), sum(index_length), sum(data_free) FROM information_schema.tables;
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 2 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
E) STATUS;  not SHOW STATUS, just STATUS;
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.